# OneToOne relation with a Joined Inheritance abstract class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have some class with an `InheritanceType.JOINED` like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A{
//some fields
}
```

Then I have 3 classes (B, C, D) that extend `A` like this one:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Audited
public class B extends A{
//fields
}
```

Now I want reference to these class inside another class, named `W`.
So I put this relation:

```
 @OneToOne
private A a;
```

But when I get the  object of `W` from my database the field of `a` is always null, and I think because it is an Abstract class.

So my question is: how can I create a `OneToOne` relation between `W` and all the concrete classes if I can't use `A` as field?

Comment: why not to use OneToOne mapping in subclasses  B,C & D rather than in W?